# Sorting imports by line length - eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

Any ideas how could I sort my imports by line "length" using `eslint`?

What I would like to achieve the behaviour shown in the attachment:

[image]

Comment: If you do this you’ll end up with some imports “jumping up and down” as you add/remove things to imports from them. This makes your diffs noisier and can cause unnecessary merge conflicts. I’d recommend a stable sort instead – sort alphabetically on the string after `from`. https://github.com/lydell/eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort#why-sort-on-from

That also spares you from deciding what order two imports with the same length should be in, how to deal with multiline imports and if comments count in line length.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I will look at it :)

Comment: Still, if for some reason this is a requirement that the OP has no control over, can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the plugin sort-imports
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amatiasq.sort-imports